# jsfiddle.net panels is not displaying in my any browser?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, mozilla, jsfiddle

i want to see some jsfiddle.net examples, but jsfiddle.net panels is not displaying properly in my any browser even though not a single link is clickable within the jsfiddle panel window.I have cleaned my all cache also.

[image]

I am getting few error messages each time in my console listed below :

```
TypeError: inp.store is not a function
 inp.store('default_value', default_text);

TypeError: this.switchLanguage is not a function
this.switchLanguage(sel);

TypeError: $(...).addEvent is not a function
$('js_lib').addEvent('change', function() {
```

Comment: i have cleaned my cache also.

Comment: Looks like some js library isn't loading.

Comment: yes but i am getting these kinds of error and problem in all jsfiddle examples, not a single one is running properly ?

Comment: right, so it'd be some library that jsfiddle needs, not one that the examples are using.

Comment: like this link http://jsfiddle.net/B4hYG/437/ is not running in my browser pc but working in another pc browser.

Comment: Doesn't change my diagnosis. Open your network tab and refresh. Click on scripts. are any failed?

Comment: Probably one of your browser extensions is causing a problem. Try turning them off and see if it fixes it.

Comment: I thought extension too at first, but, one extension affecting all browsers? certainly possible with something like norton installing a browser extension in every installed browser, but..

Comment: 1st off, ditch Norton. It's the worst, literally. Aside from them having to completely rewrite in a hurry do to source code being leaked a while back, it constantly has a way of changing everything from firewall settings to the way browser extensions *should* work. Secondly, if Norton isn't the issue, i'd suggest you get Malwarebytes ASAP and get trial for pro and run a full malware scan.

Comment: Also, i'd recommend completely replacing Norton with a combo of Avast and Malwarebytes. Those 2 alone will help keep you 99% safe and clean when used regularly.

Comment: He didn't say he was using norton, I just mentioned it because I know it installs browser extensions everywhere.

Comment: i am not using any antivirus right now.

Comment: now i am going to install Malwarebytes  as SpYk3HH suggested.